# excerpt button not going to custom post page

Tags: excerpt, buttons

Hi I made a custom post type using the CPT UI plugin, and have a excerpt button to go to it's full page.  But when I click on the button, it just loads the front page (where the button is).  Is there something wrong with the excerpt code?  I'm currently using Understrap framework.  Code below:

```
if ( ! function_exists ( 'all_excerpts_get_more_link' ) ) {
    function all_excerpts_get_more_link($post_excerpt) {

        return $post_excerpt . ' <p><a class="btn btn-secondary understrap-read-more-link" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('VIEW CASE', 'understrap')  . '</a></p>';
    }
}
add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'all_excerpts_get_more_link');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to set the global $post, otherwise your `get_the_ID()` function won't work because this code is not in a Wordpress loop.

```
function all_excerpts_get_more_link($post_excerpt) {
    global $post;

    return $post_excerpt . ' <p><a class="btn btn-secondary understrap-read-more-link" href="'. get_the_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('VIEW CASE', 'understrap')  . '</a></p>';
}

add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'all_excerpts_get_more_link');
```